# Is Riemann Zeta Function symmetrical about the real axis?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

From wikipedia,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

"Furthermore, the fact that $\zeta(s) = \zeta(s^*)^*$ for all complex s ≠ 1 ($s^*$ indicating complex conjugation) implies that the zeros of the Riemann zeta function are symmetric about the real axis."

I know the zeros are symmetrical. But what about the other values of $\zeta(s)$?
My main aim is to find out:

> Is $\zeta(s)$ symmetrical about the real axis for all $\Re(s) > 1$ ?

Comment: Isn't the answer to your question contained in the very sentence you quoted?

Comment: Well, $k^{-s}$ has mirror symmetry about the real axis...

Comment: ...and to add to Rahul's comment, that's why $\overline{f(\bar{s})}=f(s)$ is called a mirror symmetry identity.

Comment: @Rahul I wanted to find a proof of that fact. I should have said that in my question.

Comment: Ah. In that case, J.M.'s first comment should do, yes?

Comment: Yup... :) Thanks J.M.   (I am so stupid I miss these simple steps...)

Comment: rpg: You live, you learn... ;)

Comment: $k^{-s}$ has mirror symmetry about the real axis? Not where I'm from, it doesn't.

Comment: @Tony, well, $\exp(\bar{s}\ln(k))=\overline{\exp(s\ln(k))}$ for $k > 0$ ... unless you intended to say something else.

Comment: To me, if $f$ has mirror symmetry about the real axis, then $f(\bar s) = f(s)$, not $f(\bar s) = \overline{f(s)}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tony: I'm using [this way](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/04/02/01/), though if you have convincing reasons to not call it a "mirror symmetry" relation, then sure, I'll stop using the term. :)

Comment: Now you've gone from 'has mirror symmetry' to 'has a mirror symmetry relation'. But it seems to me that the OP's Question is unambiguous: 'Is $\zeta(s)$ symmetrical about the real axis?' No it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function with $f(\overline{z}) = f(z)$, then $f$ is necessarily a real constant function, so the most you can ask for is $\zeta( \overline{z}) = \overline{\zeta(z)}$, since the Riemann zeta function is not a constant function.