# Symmetry of Riemann $\zeta$ function, $\zeta(\overline{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)}$

Tags: riemann-zeta

I'm studying the Riemann $\zeta$-function, and I'm now finding out that, apparently, whenever $\rho$ is a zero of $\zeta$, $\overline{\rho}$ is also one. This follows easily from the identity $\zeta(\overline{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)}$, which I saw on wikipedia and here: [Is Riemann Zeta Function symmetrical about the real axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15559/is-riemann-zeta-function-symmetrical-about-the-real-axis).

However, how does one prove this identity?

Comment: Can you first prove it for $\mathrm{Re}\; s > 1$ ?  Then you will need to understand the analytic continuation involved for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Does $\overline{n^{s}} = n^{\overline{s}}$ hold? I'm not sure about that step. I'm trying to prove it for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}$, should I be trying to do it for the Euler product instead?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{n^{s}} = n^{\overline{s}}$ is a good first step.  What is the definition of $n^s$ for positive integer $n$ and complex $s$ ??

Comment: I was able to work it out for $\Re s > 1$, as $\overline{n^{s}} = e^{\sigma \ln{n}}(\cos{t \ln{n}} - i \sin{t \ln{n}}) = n^{\sigma}e^{-it\ln{n}} = n^{\sigma -it} = n^{\overline{s}}$.

Comment: In class, we learned about the analytic continuation through the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. Is that approach applicable to proving the identity?

Comment: No, I would say what you need to use is that the analytic continuation exists.  The two functions $$\zeta(s)\text{ and }\overline{\zeta(\overline{s})}$$ are both analytic on the connected set $\mathbb C \setminus \{1\}$, and they agree on a set with a limit point, therefore they agree everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see, because of the identity theorem?